# extend orm.yml-entity with another orm.yml-entity

Tags: orm, doctrine, yaml, extends

I got multiply .orm.yml-entites which actually need to be extended by another one. As it is described here:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses
But I do not found a solution there for orm.yml-files, this is only for annotations.

How can i achieve this?